# Eclipse: Block comment style of ctrl+shift+/ format changed in Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Tags: java, eclipse

Previous versions of eclipse block comment style for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

```
/*
line 1
line 2
line 3
*/
```

Current Version

```
/*
 * line 1
 * line 2
 * line 3
 */
```

It fhifts to right and adds extra spaces and format changes , when i do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

```
others lines of code 
whitespaces
whitespaces line 1
whitespaces line 2
whitespaces line 3
whitespaces
others lines of code
```

Even if i do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> = F the format doesn't changes , 
How do i get old formatting??

Answer (score 0):

You can change the formatting as per your preference in eclipse.

Eclipse use profile to save your formatting preferences, You can use the built-in profile or create a new profile.

In Menu Bar 
**Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter **

Under **Active Profile** you will find **Eclipse build-in**, Now you can select this and edit or create a new one.

Best practice will be to create a new profile and **Export it **, So in future, you can import your preferences in the New system or Eclipse.

There are multiple options are available to customize when you **edit** the profile.

If you are facing issue regarding shortcuts edit your preferences in :

**Window > Preferences > General > Keys**

You can also export this as CSV for future use.
  eclipse.